# Strange results when running SQL IN and NOT IN using Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

```
 , v2p AS (
      SELECT DISTINCT video_asin, product_asin 
      from video_table
      where video_asin IN (
            ‘ABC’,
            ‘CDF’,
            ‘DEF’,
            ‘FRW’)
  )
, video_data AS (
  SELECT distinct
      start_date::date,
      video_view,
      video_asin,
      page_asin
  FROM video_metrics
  WHERE 
   page_asin IN (select DISTINCT product_asin from v2p)
    AND start_date between TO_DATE('01/26/2018','MM-DD-YYYY') and TO_DATE('02/04/2018','MM-DD-YYYY') + 0.9999
) 
select sum(video_view) from video_data;
```

I’m running simple query, but I’m getting strange results with IN and NOT IN .

(1). When I do `page_asin IN (select DISTINCT product_asin from v2p),` I am getting **1,109,567** as  `select sum(video_view) from video_data;`

(2). When I do the same query but with NOT IN `page_asin NOT IN (select DISTINCT product_asin from v2p),` I am getting **7,032,405** as sum.

(3). If I remove this whole line (`page_asin IN (select DISTINCT product_asin from v2p),`) to get all results, I am getting **8,148,803.** as sum.

But I supposed that if I add (1) and (2) I should get (3).
But in reality, I am getting:  **1,109,567** + **7,032,405** = **8,141,972** AND NOT **8,148,803.**  from (3).

Why that happens? Why I am missing ~7000 video views?

Comment: Is your system online? If yes, then user may just watch 7000 videos.

Comment: No, it's not. This data is from the past: start_date between TO_DATE('01/26/2018','MM-DD-YYYY') and TO_DATE('02/04/2018','MM-DD-YYYY') + 0.9999

Comment: I would remove `DISTINCT` from `select DISTINCT product_asin from v2p` and check again. It is excessive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `NULL` value would be neither `IN` nor `NOT IN` a list.

So, `page_asin` must be `NULL` on some rows.

As a note:  The `select distinct` is redundant in the subquery.  There is no reason to include it.

Comment: Would be nice to see the use of `Not exists` and `Exists` to explain how one could work around the nulls

Comment: Yes, you are right! I have 7694 null records. That's why I got different results

Comment: @xQbert . . . I don't know what the OP wants to return.