# How to give " Only in " condition in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, data-science, data-analysis

I have a table that has columns Name, Series and Season.

| Name | series | season |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | alpha | s1 |
| abc | alpha | s2 |
| pqr | alpha | s1 |
| xyz | beta | s2 |
| xyz | gamma | s3 |
| abc | theta | s1 |

I am trying to extract the number of people who have watched only the series 'alpha', and not any other series.
How to get this count?

On giving the "where series='alpha' " condition, I get the counts of people who watched alpha, but not the counts of those who watched *only alpha* eg: abc has watched alpha as well as theta, but pqr has watched only alpha.

Comment: Do a `GROUP BY`. Use the HAVING clause to include only the desired people.

Comment: Sample data is great, but you also need to _specify_ the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a subquery to get only the names which have watched only distinct series and then filter in the where condition your specific serie

```
select count(yt.name) as  only_alpha
from yourtable yt
inner join ( select name 
             from yourtable
             group by name
             having count(distinct series) = 1
           ) yt1 on yt.name=yt1.name
where yt.series='alpha';
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/n0PavP4H

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to get the number of such people only, without their name or any further information, you can use a `NOT EXISTS` clause like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS desiredColumnName
FROM yourtable y
WHERE series = 'alpha'
AND NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT 1 FROM yourtable y1 WHERE y.name = y1.name AND series <> 'alpha');
```

Thus, you can set your condition the person must not appear in any other series but the 'alpha' one.

If the same name can occur in different seasons, you can add a `DISTINCT` to count them only once. This should only be done if really required because it can slow down the query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT name) AS desiredColumnName
FROM yourtable y
WHERE series = 'alpha'
AND NOT EXISTS 
(SELECT 1 FROM yourtable y1 WHERE y.name = y1.name AND series <> 'alpha');
```

If your description is incorrect and you need also other information, you might do better with a `GROUP BY` clause etc.

Try out here: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/A6dIZ-zf)

Answer (score 0):

You can use subquery, like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT name)
FROM t 
WHERE name NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT name
    FROM t
    WHERE series<>'alpha'
) AND series='alpha'
```

Comment: Removing the DISTINCT in the subquery will improve the performance

Answer (score 0):

You can use like below

select sum(Record) as Count from (select count(*) as Record from yourtable where series='alpha'
group by series,name having count(*)=1) as data

Check below link

https://dbfiddle.uk/1Y3WZT23

Answer (score 0):

I added some new cases to your table to see other anomalies that can happen. This is how it looks like now:

| Name | series | season |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | alpha | s1 |
| abc | alpha | s2 |
| abc | theta | s1 |
| fgh | alpha | s1 |
| fgh | alpha | s2 |
| klj | gamma | s1 |
| klj | gamma | s2 |
| klj | gamma | s3 |
| pqr | alpha | s1 |
| xyz | beta | s2 |
| xyz | gamma | s3 |

I maybe overcomplicated, but it can provide the correct result for your problem; you just need to `COUNT()` it. I tested other SQL queries under your question on my this table, but not all of them showed the correct figure. I doesn't recommend to use `NOT IN ( sub query )` for the following reasons:

1. [Strange results when running SQL IN and NOT IN using Redshift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50354907/strange-results-when-running-sql-in-and-not-in-using-redshift)
2. [Optimization for Large IN Lists](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_in_condition.html)
3. [Consider using EXISTS instead of IN with a subquery](https://www.red-gate.com/hub/product-learning/sql-prompt/consider-using-not-exists-instead-not-subquery)

Please find my code here:

```
WITH helper_table as
(
    SELECT      "Name",
                series,
                count(1) as seasons_watched
    FROM        your_table
    GROUP BY    1, 2
)
------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT      t1."Name"
FROM
(
        SELECT      "Name",
                    count(1) as is_watched_at_least_one_series_of_alpha
        FROM        helper_table
        WHERE       series = 'alpha'
        GROUP BY    1
) t1

INNER JOIN
(
        SELECT      "Name",
                    count(1) as watched_exactly_one_series_so_far
        FROM        helper_table
        GROUP BY    1
        HAVING      count(1) = 1
) t2
ON          t2."Name" = t1."Name"
;
```

Hope it helps!